# Spring integration - imap - credentials issue

Tags: imap, credentials, spring-integration

Here is my xml:

```
<mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="imapAdapter"
                                  store-uri="imaps://[avita.nir@gmail.com]:[secretPass]@imap.gmail.com/INBOX"                                   
                                  channel="recieveEmailChannel"                                         
                                  should-delete-messages="false"
                                  should-mark-messages-as-read="true"                                     
                                  auto-startup="true"                                                                           
                                  java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties">
```

For some reason when i type this "store-uri" i get this exception (null password):

```
    DEBUG: protocolConnect returning false, host=gmail.com], user=[avita.nir, password=<null>
21 יול 2013 15:32:05 ERROR LoggingHandler - org.springframework.integration.MessagingException:      failure occurred while polling for mail
at org.springframework.integration.mail.MailReceivingMessageSource.receive(MailReceivingMessageSource.java:73)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.doPoll(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:89)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:145)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:143)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:206)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:48)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:201)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53)
at              org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at         java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolE  xecutor.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: failure occurred while receiving from folder
at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.receive(AbstractMailReceiver.java:240)
at org.springframework.integration.mail.MailReceivingMessageSource.receive(MailReceivingMessageSource.java:59)
... 18 more
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect, no password specified?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the [ ] and you should be good - also if the username or password contains special characters you will have to escape them.

It's always useful to set `mail.debug` to true for these issues and you'll get more information on the console.

Comment: Had to escape the @ in my user name. Thanks Gary!