# Found javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect, no password specified? while listenning new mails where the password is correct

Tags: java, spring-integration, dsl

This exception i got while connecting imap gmail store using spring integration. Please have a look at the code
{@Autowired
        private IntegrationFlowContext flowContext;

```
    public void startMail(String user, String pw) {
        IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows
                .from(Mail.imapIdleAdapter(imapUrl(user, pw))
                        .javaMailProperties(p -> p.put("mail.debug", "true"))
                        //.userFlag("testSIUserFlag") // needed by the SI test server - not needed if server supports /SEEN
                        .headerMapper(new DefaultMailHeaderMapper()))
                .handle(System.out::println)
                .get();
        this.flowContext.registration(flow).register();
    }}
```

where imapUrl(user, pw) returns the url as imap://xyz.abc@gmail.com:xxxxx@imap.gmail.com:993/INBOX

please help me to get rid of this exception.

Note: i read one of the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772435/spring-integration-imap-credentials-issue?answertab=votes#tab-top) saying need to escape '@' in credentials. As am novice to java spring boot, please let me know how i can escape '@'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Artem! It worked. Actually when it is a @gmail.com. don't need this suffix in the IMAP URL - just your account. For example my one when I connect is like this:

```
imaps://clericsmail:[APP_PASSWORD]@imap.gmail.com/INBOX
```

where `APP_PASSWORD` I can't show you because that one is what I configured for according those GMail recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

GMail doesn't support JavaMail clients, by default; you have to enable "less secure clients" (or something similar).

use `%40` to replace `@`.

https://www.werockyourweb.com/url-escape-characters/

Comment: You should only replace the first one.

Comment: Yeah... "Less secure" didn't work for me, but I have figured out it with this https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833. So, two-factory and app password. Also see here for java mail properties special for GMail:  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3257#issuecomment-618565996

Comment: Gary, we should be replacing @ in userid or password only. So i did, still no luck

Comment: Artem, after adding all relevant properties...still facing same issue

Comment: Actually when it is a `@gmail.com`. don't need this suffix in the IMAP URL - just your account. For example my one when I connect is like this: `imaps://clericsmail:[APP_PASSWORD]@imap.gmail.com/INBOX`, where `APP_PASSWORD` I can't show you because that one is what I configured for according those GMail recommendations.

Comment: Thanks Artem, Gary  it works. the protocol am using imap instead imaps and by removing suffix. gmail need a secure connection. But now facing FolderCloseException. please suggest any pointers.